# Quiero cambiar un checkbox por un boton

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Estoy haciendo una tienda en prestashop y quiero cambiar el checkbox que se usa para aceptar los terminos y condiciones por un boton que diga acepto.

El archivo payment.tpl tiene este codigo:

```
<form id="conditions-to-approve" method="GET">
  <ul>
    {foreach from=$conditions_to_approve item="condition" key="condition_name"}
      <li class="flex_container flex_start">
          <span class="custom-input-box">
            <input  id    = "conditions_to_approve[{$condition_name}]"
                    name  = "conditions_to_approve[{$condition_name}]"
                    required
                    type  = "checkbox"
                    value = "1"
                    class = "ps-shown-by-js custom-input"
            >
            <span class="custom-input-item custom-input-checkbox"><i class="fto-ok-1 checkbox-checked"></i></span>
          </span>
          <label class="js-terms flex_child" for="conditions_to_approve[{$condition_name}]">
            {$condition nofilter}
          </label>
      </li>
    {/foreach}
  </ul>
</form>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué es lo que te falla?

Comment: No me falla el checkbox, pero lo quiero cambiar por un boton para que sea mas explicito el hecho de aceptar los terminos. y no se como modificar el codigo para cambiarlo por un boton.

Comment: Me refiero a qué es lo complicado de cambiarlo? por lo que noto sólo sería modificar la propiedad type a **button**... lo intentaste?

Comment: Si, pero al hacerlo sigue teniendo la forma de un checkbox (apariencia), solo que ya no se marca o desmarca al darle click.

Comment: Hay una pregunta similar aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover y creo que está bastante bien darle forma con el css y hacer el hover tal y como lo hace aquí: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías crear algo similar lo siguiente utilizando el tag `<label>`:

```css
button.custom-checkbox {}

/* oculto el input */
button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/* oculto el texto */
button.custom-checkbox span {
  display: none;
}
/* si está activo el input */
button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* si está inactivo el input */
button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + label span.not-active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button class="custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
  <label for="check">
    <span class="active">Cancelar</span>
    <span class="not-active">Acepto</span>
  </label>
</button>
```

---

Este sería con el ejemplo que pasaste, no lo vas a poder visualizar por acá pero sí en tu local una vez que copies lo mismo:

```css
button.custom-checkbox {}

/* oculto el input */
button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/* oculto el texto */
button.custom-checkbox span {
  display: none;
}
/* si está activo el input */
button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* si está inactivo el input */
button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + label span.not-active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id="conditions-to-approve" method="GET">
  <ul>
    {foreach from=$conditions_to_approve item="condition" key="condition_name"}
      <li class="flex_container flex_start">
        <button class="custom-checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="conditions_to_approve[{$condition_name}]"
            name="conditions_to_approve[{$condition_name}]"
            required
            value="1"
            class="ps-shown-by-js custom-input" />
          <label
            for="conditions_to_approve[{$condition_name}]"
            class="js-terms flex_child">
            <span class="active">Cancelar</span>
            <span class="not-active">Acepto</span>
          </label>
        </button>
      </li>
    {/foreach}
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no se bien como implementarlo a mi codigo, la verdad no he trabajado con esto nunca, si muestra el boton pero no puedo conseguir que deje de mostrar el checkbox

Comment: En el CSS hay una línea que oculta el input: `button.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }`.

Comment: Ahí lo edité poniéndolo en el fragmento de código que pasaste pero te advierto que no vas a poder visualizarlo por acá hasta que lo copies en tu local.